# Прослушивание классической музыки — как назвать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как назвать рабочее прослушивание классической музыки критиком, педагогом, дирижёром? Аналитическим слушанием?

Answer (score 0):

Прослушивание на уровне *эстетического созерцания* (*художественного восприятия*):

http://ponjatija.ru/node/465